# Using except AttributeError with defaultdict to Initialize List

Tags: python, attributeerror, defaultdict

I need to loop through some data and create a nested dictionary 4 keys deep with the first 3 keys having values of type dict and the last key having a value of type list that will store integers. I want to avoid KeyErrors so i am using defaultdict(). I have created a recursive function that calls defaultdict() and a try/except to look for AttributeError to discover if a list has already been created in the defaultdict.  Is it safe to use a try/except to look AttributeError or might some other errors manifest itself that i should consider?

```
def dict_factory():
    return defaultdict(dict_factory)
nestedDict = dict_factory()
try:
    nestedDict[k1][k2][k3][k4].append(someInt)
except AttributeError:
    nestedDict[k1][k2][k3][k4] = [someInt]
```

I found that the following also works.   Would I be better off using this code?:

```
nestedDict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))))
```

Comment: What is `dict_factor`?

Comment: corrected.  should have been dict_factory. thanks

Comment: I find your approach very clever and don't see a problem with it for now. Consider subclassing `defaultdict` to encapsulate your code.